# Utilizar uma função várias vezes

Tags: javascript, svg

Criei uma função que cria um certo relógio. O objetivo é utilizar a função para reutilizar várias vezes, alterando os parâmetros da posição `x` e `y`. Utilizo a função `setInterval` para atualizar todos os segundos. O problema é que a função só está a ser utilizada uma vez.

Código completo: https://jsfiddle.net/p53xcwcj/

```js
    var cont = 0;
 
 function horloge_dynamique(x,y,diametre,decalage){
  
  var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
  cont++;
  
  //cree circle
  var newCircle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
  newCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'circle' + cont);
  newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'stroke-width',2);
  newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'stroke','black');
  newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'fill','Aqua');
  svg.appendChild(newCircle);
  
  //cree aiguille heure
  var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
  newLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'heure' + cont);
  newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke","red");
  newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width","4");
  svg.appendChild(newLine);
  
  //cree aiguille minute
  var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
  newLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'min' + cont);
  newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke","orange");
  newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width","2");
  svg.appendChild(newLine);
  
  //cree aiguille seconde
  var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
  newLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'sec' + cont);
  newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke","black");
  newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width","1");
  svg.appendChild(newLine);
  
  //var circle = document.getElementById("circle_horloge");
  var circle = document.getElementById("circle" + cont);
  circle.setAttribute("cx",x);
  circle.setAttribute("cy",y);
  circle.setAttribute("r",diametre);
  
  //heure
  //var aiguille_heure = document.getElementById("heure");
  var aiguille_heure = document.getElementById("heure"+ cont);
  aiguille_heure.setAttribute("x1",x);
  aiguille_heure.setAttribute("y1",y);
  aiguille_heure.setAttribute("x2",x);
  aiguille_heure.setAttribute("y2",(y-diametre)+diametre/3);
             
  //minutes
  var aiguille_min = document.getElementById("min"+ cont);
  aiguille_min.setAttribute("x1",x);
  aiguille_min.setAttribute("y1",y);
  aiguille_min.setAttribute("x2",x);
  aiguille_min.setAttribute("y2",(y-diametre)+diametre/5);
  
  //secondes
  var aiguille_sec = document.getElementById("sec"+cont);
  aiguille_sec.setAttribute("x1",x);
  aiguille_sec.setAttribute("y1",y);
  aiguille_sec.setAttribute("x2",x);
  aiguille_sec.setAttribute("y2",y-diametre);
  
  
  setInterval(function(){ 
   var d = new Date(); //date
  
   var heure_decalage = d.getHours()+decalage;
   var minute = d.getMinutes();
   var seconds = d.getSeconds();
   
   var heure_calc = (30*((heure_decalage)%12) + (d.getMinutes()/2));
   var minute_calc = 6*minute;
   var seconde_calc = 6*seconds;
   
   var heure = document.getElementById("heure"+ cont);
   var min = document.getElementById("min"+ cont);
   var sec = document.getElementById("sec"+ cont);
   
   //title horloge
   document.getElementById("circle"+cont).setAttribute("title", heure_decalage + ":" + minute);
   
   heure.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate('+ heure_calc +" "+ x +" "+ y +')');
   
   min.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate('+ minute_calc +" "+ x +" "+ y +')');
   sec.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate('+ seconde_calc +" "+ x +" "+ y +')');
   //setTimeout("r(x,y,diametre,decalage,cont)", 1000); 
 
  }, 1000)
 
 }
 
 var x = 500;
 var y = 250;
 
 var x1 = 200;
 var y1 = 100;
 
 var diametre = 100;

 var decalage = 0; 
 
 horloge_dynamique(200,200,diametre,decalage);
 
 horloge_dynamique(100,100,diametre,decalage);
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="800">
</svg>
```

Comment: Por favor, apresente uma versão mais resumida do seu problema e coloque todo o cõdigo na prõpria pergunta ao invés de linkar para um site externo (O stackoverflow também é capaz de rodar snippets de javascript se você quiser).  Da forma atual está meio difícil de entender a sua pergunta e o seu código tem muitos detalhes desnecessários.

Comment: só não entendi por que tomei -1 se a explicação foi pertinente, só não tinha colocado o código fonte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu principal problema é a variável `cont` que é uma só, e não uma por relógio. Foi só eu introduzir uma variável `myCont` por relógio e usá-la ao invés da `cont` que funcionou.

Aqui está o jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p7L3jf5L/

Aqui vai o código:

```js
var cont = 0;

function horloge_dynamique(x, y, diametre, decalage) {

    var myCont = cont;
    var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
    cont++;

    //cree circle
    var newCircle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'circle' + myCont);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'stroke-width', 2);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'stroke', 'black');
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'fill', 'Aqua');
    svg.appendChild(newCircle);

    //cree aiguille heure
    var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'heure' + myCont);
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "red");
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "4");
    svg.appendChild(newLine);

    //cree aiguille minute
    var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'min' + myCont);
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "orange");
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "2");
    svg.appendChild(newLine);

    //cree aiguille seconde
    var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'sec' + myCont);
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "black");
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "1");
    svg.appendChild(newLine);

    //var circle = document.getElementById("circle_horloge");
    var circle = document.getElementById("circle" + myCont);
    circle.setAttribute("cx", x);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", y);
    circle.setAttribute("r", diametre);

    //heure
    //var aiguille_heure = document.getElementById("heure");
    var aiguille_heure = document.getElementById("heure" + myCont);
    aiguille_heure.setAttribute("x1", x);
    aiguille_heure.setAttribute("y1", y);
    aiguille_heure.setAttribute("x2", x);
    aiguille_heure.setAttribute("y2", (y - diametre) + diametre / 3);

    //minutes
    var aiguille_min = document.getElementById("min" + myCont);
    aiguille_min.setAttribute("x1", x);
    aiguille_min.setAttribute("y1", y);
    aiguille_min.setAttribute("x2", x);
    aiguille_min.setAttribute("y2", (y - diametre) + diametre / 5);

    //secondes
    var aiguille_sec = document.getElementById("sec" + myCont);
    aiguille_sec.setAttribute("x1", x);
    aiguille_sec.setAttribute("y1", y);
    aiguille_sec.setAttribute("x2", x);
    aiguille_sec.setAttribute("y2", y - diametre);


    setInterval(function(){ 
        var d = new Date(); //date

        var heure_decalage = d.getHours() + decalage;
        var minute = d.getMinutes();
        var seconds = d.getSeconds();

        var heure_calc = (30 * ((heure_decalage) % 12) + (d.getMinutes() / 2));
        var minute_calc = 6 * minute;
        var seconde_calc = 6 * seconds;

        var heure = document.getElementById("heure" + myCont);
        var min = document.getElementById("min" + myCont);
        var sec = document.getElementById("sec" + myCont);

        //title horloge
        document.getElementById("circle" + myCont).setAttribute("title", heure_decalage + ":" + minute);

        heure.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + heure_calc + " " + x + " " + y + ')');

        min.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + minute_calc + " " + x + " " + y + ')');
        sec.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + seconde_calc + " " + x + " " + y + ')');
        //setTimeout("r(x, y, diametre, decalage, myCont)", 1000); 
    }, 1000);
}

var x = 500;
var y = 250;

var x1 = 200;
var y1 = 100;

var diametre = 100;

var decalage = 0; 

horloge_dynamique(200, 200, diametre, decalage);

horloge_dynamique(100, 100, diametre, decalage);
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="800">
</svg>
```

Comment: resolvido, o mycount gera outro ID fiz mudando a assinatura da função em vez de alterar todas as linhas dentro da função, mas, ta resolvido igual.

Comment: @MaisonSakamoto Legal que você tenha chegado nisso também, mas saiba que não fui eu quem negativou a sua resposta. Pelo contrário, acabei de te dar +1 também.

Answer (score 3):

onde estiver escrito getElementById o javascript pegará somente o primeiro elemento que tiver este ID, para fazer 2 relógios, terá que mudar seu código para pegar ajustar essa parte.

https://jsfiddle.net/p53xcwcj/3/

**HTML**

```
<svg id="svg01" width="100%" height="800">    </svg>
<svg id="svg02" width="100%" height="800">    </svg>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    //var cont = 0;

function horloge_dynamique(id,cont,x,y,diametre,decalage){

    var svg = document.getElementById(id);
    //cont++;

    //cree circle
    var newCircle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'circle' + cont);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'stroke-width',2);
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'stroke','black');
    newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,'fill','Aqua');
    svg.appendChild(newCircle);

    //cree aiguille heure
    var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'heure' + cont);
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke","red");
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width","4");
    svg.appendChild(newLine);

    //cree aiguille minute
    var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'min' + cont);
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke","orange");
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width","2");
    svg.appendChild(newLine);

    //cree aiguille seconde
    var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'sec' + cont);
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke","black");
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width","1");
    svg.appendChild(newLine);

    //var circle = document.getElementById("circle_horloge");
    var circle = document.getElementById("circle" + cont);
    circle.setAttribute("cx",x);
    circle.setAttribute("cy",y);
    circle.setAttribute("r",diametre);

    //heure
    //var aiguille_heure = document.getElementById("heure");
    var aiguille_heure = document.getElementById("heure"+ cont);
    aiguille_heure.setAttribute("x1",x);
    aiguille_heure.setAttribute("y1",y);
    aiguille_heure.setAttribute("x2",x);
    aiguille_heure.setAttribute("y2",(y-diametre)+diametre/3);

    //minutes
    var aiguille_min = document.getElementById("min"+ cont);
    aiguille_min.setAttribute("x1",x);
    aiguille_min.setAttribute("y1",y);
    aiguille_min.setAttribute("x2",x);
    aiguille_min.setAttribute("y2",(y-diametre)+diametre/5);

    //secondes
    var aiguille_sec = document.getElementById("sec"+cont);
    aiguille_sec.setAttribute("x1",x);
    aiguille_sec.setAttribute("y1",y);
    aiguille_sec.setAttribute("x2",x);
    aiguille_sec.setAttribute("y2",y-diametre);


    setInterval(function(){ 
        var d = new Date(); //date

        var heure_decalage = d.getHours()+decalage;
        var minute = d.getMinutes();
        var seconds = d.getSeconds();

        var heure_calc = (30*((heure_decalage)%12) + (d.getMinutes()/2));
        var minute_calc = 6*minute;
        var seconde_calc = 6*seconds;

        var heure = document.getElementById("heure"+ cont);
        var min = document.getElementById("min"+ cont);
        var sec = document.getElementById("sec"+ cont);

        //title horloge
        document.getElementById("circle"+cont).setAttribute("title", heure_decalage + ":" + minute);

        heure.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate('+ heure_calc +" "+ x +" "+ y +')');

        min.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate('+ minute_calc +" "+ x +" "+ y +')');
        sec.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate('+ seconde_calc +" "+ x +" "+ y +')');
        //setTimeout("r(x,y,diametre,decalage,cont)", 1000); 

    }, 1000)

}

var x = 500;
var y = 250;

var x1 = 200;
var y1 = 100;

var diametre = 100;

var decalage = 0; 

horloge_dynamique('svg01',1,x,y,diametre,decalage);

horloge_dynamique('svg02',2,x1,y1,diametre,decalage);
```